# Как сделать сегмент пончика в HTML5, используя только CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Как сделать эту фигуру, используя только `CSS`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что я пробовал:

```css
.button-up {
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 35px solid transparent;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-up"></div>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49907944/7394871

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вариант попроще:

```css
.block {
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Можно с помощью `:before` фон сделать, чтобы обводка была

Comment: @kizoso, это само собой, однако, надеюсь в скором будущем нам не придётся делать с такими костылями в `CSS` =) А пока, в данном случае лучший вариант — `SVG`

Answer (score 5):

Я бы использовал  `линейный / радиальный градиент` следующим образом:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:
  linear-gradient(-30deg, white 50%,transparent 0),
  linear-gradient(30deg, white 50%,transparent 0),
  radial-gradient(circle at center,transparent 31%,blue 30%,blue 100%, transparent 51%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

И с `border`:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to top,white 59%,transparent 0),
  linear-gradient(-30deg, white calc(50% - 4px),green calc(50% - 4px),green 50%,transparent 0),
  linear-gradient(30deg, white calc(50% - 4px),green calc(50% - 4px),green 50%,transparent 0),
  radial-gradient(circle at center,transparent calc(30% - 4px),green calc(30% - 4px),green 30%,blue 30%,blue calc(70% - 3px),green 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Вы также можете рассмотреть решение с SVG, которое может быть проще:

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64' width='300' height='300' fill='blue'>
  <path stroke="green" stroke-width=1 d='M24 32 C28 28 37 28 40 32 L52 22 C38 8 26 8 12 22 Z' />
</svg>
```

Вот еще одна идея с `clip-path`:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:
  radial-gradient(circle at center,transparent 31%,blue 30%,blue 100%, transparent 51%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 50%, 100% 0);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 50%, 100% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```